# When Is $a^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv a \pmod n$ true?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

Is $a^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv a \pmod n$ always true?

In what conditions is $a^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv a \pmod n$ true?  I know that $a^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv a \pmod n$ is true whenever $a$ and $n$ are coprime, but it is false for a=2, n=4. What are sufficient circumstances for  $a^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv a \pmod n$ to be true even when $a$ and $b$ are not coprime?

Comment: No, e.g., $a=2$, $n=4$, then $\varphi(n)=2$ and $2^{2+1}\not\equiv 2\pmod{4}$.

Comment: Did you mean $a$ and $\color{red}n$ are not coprime?  You want $n$ square-free

Answer (score 4):

A condition that is both necessary an sufficient for the congruence to hold, is  that $a$ is coprime to $\frac n{\gcd(a,n)}$.

Suppose $p|n$ and $p|a$ for some prime $p$.  Suppose $p^i$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$.  Then the property of $p^j$ dividing $a$ for $j\leq i$ depends only on the residue class of $a \mod n$.

As $\phi(n)>0$ for all $n$, we have that $a^{\phi(n)+1}$ will be divisible by a higher power $j\leq i$ of $p$ than $a$, unless $p^i|a$.

Repeating this argument for all primes $p|\gcd(a,n)$, we conclude that if $$a^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv a \mod n,$$
then $a$ is coprime to $\frac n{\gcd(a,n)}$.

Conversely if $a$ is coprime to $\frac n{\gcd(a,n)}$, write $n=uv$, with $u$ a product of primes dividing $a$ and $v$ a product of primes not dividing $a$.  We have \begin{eqnarray*}a&\equiv&0 \mod u,\\a^{\phi(n)+1}&\equiv& a \mod v,
\end{eqnarray*} so $$a^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv a \mod n,$$ as $u,v$ are coprime.